# Steps to checkmate in my endgame position

Tags: endgame, checkmate

There is a black bishop at a4, black queen at b4, a black king at e5 and a white king at c1. There is a checkmate in 3 moves. I want to know what the moves are.

```
[FEN "8/8/8/4k3/bq6/8/8/2K5 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: If you can take a screenshot or use the pgn editor that would be helpful. Are those all the pieces left?

Comment: Yes..this is for my Husband. I know nothing about chess

Answer (score 6):

Black mates in three with

```
[FEN "8/8/8/4k3/bq6/8/8/2K5 b - - 0 1"]

1... Qb7 2. Kd2 Qe4 3. Kc1 (3. Kc3 Qd4#) Qc2#
```

The paradoxical Qb7 is the only solution, you can check this with an [endgame database](http://www.shredderchess.com/online-chess/online-databases/endgame-database.html).

Comment: While OP doesn't mention it, this is almost certainly a chess problem; in addition to the amazingly quiet first move, note that in the 3. Kc3 variation the ending position is a so-called "model" mate: all of Black's pieces participate in the mate directly, and each square in the field of the White king is covered by only one of Black's pieces.